Fabric Lakehouse access Kotlin ( Not working ) Similar code working in Python
Kotlin code not allowing to connect to the Fabric Lakehouse -
i am getting error as follows I am limited in Java /Kotlin - I am out of options now spent 6 hours on GPT, Youtube to get this code equivalent of python get working in via android app ( client need ) but no success please help ...how i can get the list of my Lakehouse using Java/Kotlin
Error :
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to use package-private MethodHandles.Lookup constructor.
                                                                                                                                                at com.azure.core.implementation.ReflectionUtils.<clinit>(ReflectionUtils.java:84)
                                                                                                                                                at com.azure.core.util.ExpandableStringEnum.getDefaultConstructor(ExpandableStringEnum.java:88) 
                                                                                                                                                at com.azure.core.util.ExpandableStringEnum.$r8$lambda$E-5gDoh7TMDRM8qyQUcR6yo_L1s(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                                                                                at com.azure.core.util.ExpandableStringEnum$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.apply(D8$$SyntheticClass:0) 
                                                                                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1713) 
                                                                                                                                                at com.azure.core.util.ExpandableStringEnum.fromString(ExpandableStringEnum.java:68) 
                                                                                                                                                at com.azure.identity.implementation.RegionalAuthority.fromString(RegionalAuthority.java:287) 
                                                                                                                                                at com.azure.identity.implementation.RegionalAuthority.<clinit>(RegionalAuthority.java:19) 
                                                                                                                                                at com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClientOptions.<init>(IdentityClientOptions.java:84) 
                                                                                                                                                at com.azure.identity.CredentialBuilderBase.<init>(CredentialBuilderBase.java:35) 
                                                                                                                                                at com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder.<init>(DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder.java:38) 
                                                                                                                                                at com.example.aznyy2_kotlin.MainActivity.interactWithAzure(MainActivity.kt:32) 
                                                                                                                                                at com.example.aznyy2_kotlin.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:24) 
                                                                                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8975) 
                                                                                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8944) 
                                                                                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456) 
                                                                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4146) 
                                                                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4322) 
                                                                                                                                                at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
                                                                                                                                                at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139) 
                                                                                                                                                at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96) 
                                                                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2685) 
                                                                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230) 
                                                                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319) 
                                                                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8919) 
                                                                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578) 
                                                                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103) 
                                                                                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.<init> [class java.lang.Class]
                                                                                                                                                at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3325)
                                                                                                                                                at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:3063)
                                                                                                                                                at com.azure.core.implementation.ReflectionUtils.<clinit>(ReflectionUtils.java:76)
                                                                                                                                                at com.azure.core.util.ExpandableStringEnum.getDefaultConstructor(ExpandableStringEnum.java:88) 
                                                                                                                                                at com.azure.core.util.ExpandableStringEnum.$r8$lambda$E-5gDoh7TMDRM8qyQUcR6yo_L1s(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                                                                                at com.azure.core.util.ExpandableStringEnum$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.apply(D8$$SyntheticClass:0) 
                                                                                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1713) 
                                                                                                                                                at com.azure.core.util.ExpandableStringEnum.fromString(ExpandableStringEnum.java:68) 
                                                                                                                                                at com.azure.identity.implementation.RegionalAuthority.fromString(RegionalAuthority.java:287) 
                                                                                                                                                at com.azure.identity.implementation.RegionalAuthority.<clinit>(RegionalAuthority.java:19) 
                                                                                                                                                at com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClientOptions.<init>(IdentityClientOptions.java:84) 
                                                                                                                                                at com.azure.identity.CredentialBuilderBase.<init>(CredentialBuilderBase.java:35) 
                                                                                                                                                at com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder.<init>(DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder.java:38) 
                                                                                                                                                at com.example.aznyy2_kotlin.MainActivity.interactWithAzure(MainActivity.kt:32) 
                                                                                                                                                at com.example.aznyy2_kotlin.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:24) 
                                                                                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8975) 
                                                                                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8944) 
                                                                                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456) 
                                                                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4146) 
                                                                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4322) 
                                                                                                                                                at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
                                                                                                                                                at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139) 
                                                                                                                                                at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96) 
                                                                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2685) 
                                                                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230) 
                                                                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319) 
                                                                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8919) 
                                                                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578) 
                                                                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103) 

Here is the COde i am using in KOTLIN,
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder
import com.azure.storage.file.datalake.DataLakeServiceClient
import com.azure.storage.file.datalake.DataLakeServiceClientBuilder
import com.azure.storage.file.datalake.models.ListPathsOptions
import com.azure.storage.file.datalake.models.PathItem
import java.time.Duration

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val ACCOUNT_NAME = "onelake"
    private val WORKSPACE_NAME = "Testworkspace"
    private val DATA_PATH = "Testlakehouse.Lakehouse/Files/"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Example method to interact with Azure
        interactWithAzure()
    }

    private fun interactWithAzure() {
        val accountUrl = "https://$ACCOUNT_NAME.dfs.fabric.microsoft.com"
        Log.d("AzureExample01", accountUrl)

        val credential = try {
            DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("AzureExampleError", "Failed to create DefaultAzureCredential", e)
            return
        }

        Log.d("AzureExample02", "Credential successfully created: $credential")

        val serviceClient = try {
            DataLakeServiceClientBuilder()
                .endpoint(accountUrl)
                .credential(credential)
                .buildClient()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("AzureExampleError", "Failed to create DataLakeServiceClient", e)
            return
        }

        Log.d("AzureExample03", "Service client successfully created: $serviceClient")

        val fileSystemClient = try {
            serviceClient.getFileSystemClient(WORKSPACE_NAME)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("AzureExampleError", "Failed to create FileSystemClient", e)
            return
        }

        Log.d("AzureExample04", "File system client successfully created: $fileSystemClient")

        try {
            val listPathsOptions = ListPathsOptions().setPath(DATA_PATH).setRecursive(false)
            Log.d("AzureExample05", "Listing files in the directory:")
            fileSystemClient.listPaths(listPathsOptions, Duration.ofMinutes(1)).forEach { pathItem: PathItem ->
                Log.d("AzureExample06", "${pathItem.name}")
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("AzureExampleError", "Failed to list paths", e)
        }
    }
}

ANd here is the equivalent code i used in VS and it worked perfectly fine  ( i can see the list of the Lakehouse contents ) but similar code in Kotlin or Java is not at all working.
from azure.storage.filedatalake import (
    DataLakeServiceClient,
    DataLakeDirectoryClient,
    FileSystemClient
)
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

# Set your account, workspace, and item path here
ACCOUNT_NAME = "onelake"
WORKSPACE_NAME = "Testworkspace"
DATA_PATH = "Testlakehouse.Lakehouse/Files/"

def main():
    #Create a service client using the default Azure credential

    account_url = f"https://{ACCOUNT_NAME}.dfs.fabric.microsoft.com"
    token_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url, credential=token_credential)
    
    print(token_credential)
    print(account_url)
    print(service_client)
   

    #Create a file system client for the workspace
    file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(WORKSPACE_NAME)
        
    #List a directory within the filesystem
    paths = file_system_client.get_paths(path=DATA_PATH)
    print(paths)
    for path in paths:
        print(path.name + '\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

